# array of base64 strings to image in tableview

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, base64

I have an array consists of images in the format base 64 string I need to bind in table view. I have tried the below code to convert base 64 to image code

> ```
> UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataFromBase64String:result]];
> ```

But I have array. How to get images from array which are in base 64 format. Any code will be helpful.Kindly provide in swift

Comment: "array which are in base 64 format."? You mean an array of String in base 64? `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataFromBase64String:result[indexPath.row]]];`

Comment: `result` is an `NSArray`?

Comment: result is nsstring which i converted from nsarray in order to use base64string conversion code  and @Larme it worked thanks :)

Comment: why it has been downvoted for no reason.. simply awful.....to reduce my reputations....shame on that guy who downvoted without guts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```c
- (UIImage *)decodeBase64ToImage:(NSString *)strEncodeData {
  NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:strEncodeData options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
  return [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}
```

then inside your tableview cell, call like this:

```
cell.imageView.image = [self decodeBase64ToImage:result[indexPath.row]];;
```

> Swift 3.0

```
func decodeBase64image(toImage strEncodeData: String) -> UIImage {
var data = Data(base64Encoded: strEncodeData, options:.ignoreUnknownCharacters)
return UIImage(data: data)!
}
```

then

```
cell.imageView?.image = decodeBase64image(toImage: result[indexPath.row])
```

Comment: thanks can you provide me same for swift? it will be more helpful

Comment: thanks..but it throws an error "type of expression is ambiguous without more context" .My code is as       below                                                                    func decodeBase64(toImage strEncodeData: String) -> UIImage {
        var data = Data(base64Encoded: countryFlagRxed, options:.ignoreUnknownCharacters)
        return UIImage(data: data)!
    }
countryFlagRxed is an array containing base64 strings

Comment: @gopinath no need to add countryFagRxed inside func